# Backup MySQL, using Screen and Crontab

Tags: mysql, cron, gnu-screen

I'm trying to backup my database's table every day, using mysqldump, screen and crontab. If I run only `mysqldump`, it dumps correctly, but if I do it trough `screen`, the output file is blank.

## Editing Crontab

```
crontab -e
```

## Adding Command

```
0 0 * * * screen -dmS MYDATABASE_MYTABLE_backup mysqldump -u MYUSERNAME -pMYPASSWORD -h MYHOSTNAME MYDATABASE MYTABLE --compress | gzip > /root/backup/database/MYDATABASE_MYTABLE_`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want to accomplish with screen in this scenario and why it is needed at all.
But you are piping (with | .. > ) the output of screen to the dump file, not the output of the program which runs in screen.
You either have to enclose the complete commando with quotes - or probably better put the commando in a script file and simpy call the script instead

myscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysqldump -u MYUSERNAME -pMYPASSWORD -h MYHOSTNAME MYDATABASE MYTABLE --compress | gzip > /root/backup/database/MYDATABASE_MYTABLE_`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`.sql.gz
```

screen -dmS MYDATABASE_MYTABLE_backup myscript.sh